# Can you sue the airline if you get sick after flying?

Tags: air-travel, health

I worry about getting flu from all the germs going around an airplane, because of its design flaws. The airlines  know you have a 1 to 5 chance to get sick after a flight, because research has been done. But they don't act on it.

I just got sick after a flight because of a dirty packed airplane and unscreened sick passengers going abroad. Can I make a claim against the airline? What about travel insurance?

Comment: The air inside airplane cabins gets recycled faster than the air in your room. The chances of catching the flu in an airplane is not more than the chances of catching it from a bus ride, or while waiting for your turn at the doctor's clinic, or any other crowded place. The thing you should worry about is touching stuff then playing with your nose or eyes.

Comment: What is the source of your "! in 5" figure? Whether your travel insurance covers this will depend on the wording of the policy.

Comment: Sorry, no.  Cabin air is cleaner then most any other place, being remixed and filtered usually under 5 minutes.  Theoretically, all cabin air can be new air every ~20 minutes.

Comment: @Johns-305 that does not stop him from seeing though, only prevents him from winning if you are correct

Comment: Care to back up this claim that research has been made and the airlines ignore it?

Comment: Airplane air is very dry, so low risk. But it is what you touch. Legally? I think it is a well know risk (traveling, many people together, coming from all world [it is always "winter" somewhere]), so it is also your "fault", and considering the prices of flight, probably you cannot claim you expect hygiene like first class restaurant

Answer (score 9):

You can absolutely sue the airline if you get sick after flying with them.

You will lose, and if it makes it as far as the courts then you'll almost certainly need to pay their legal costs as well as your own.  However that does not stop you from suing them.

Answer (score 4):

This from Patrick Smith's excellent book *Cockpit Confidential*:

> Studies have shown that a crowded airplane is no more germ-laden than other enclosed spaces - and usually less. Those underfloor filters are described by manufacturers as being of hospital quality. I needn’t be reminded that hospitals are notorious viral incubators, but Boeing says that between 94 and 99.9 percent of airborne microbes are captured, and there’s a total changeover of air every two or three minutes - far more frequently than occurs in offices, movie theaters, or classrooms.

You definitely have a right to sue anyone you like, but you might want to make sure the facts support your position before you do, to avoid embarrassing and expensive outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

@Doc has already given a great straight answer to the question asked.

To expand on that:
How will you know that you got sick at the plane and not at your

1. holiday destination
2. departure airport
3. arrival airport
4. any public transport taken anywhere during that day
5. anybody else you've had contact with

You will know it takes symptoms a bit to show up ([for flu - one to four days](https://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/qa/how-long-does-it-take-for-flu-symptoms-to-show-up)). I remember my flu symptoms started appearing only when I was already home! This isn't something that you can prove to anybody that you got it from a specific location or person.